# Can't add foreign key to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I've checked that none of the two tables has any foreign keys. I've checked that they both have Id of type uniqueidentifier. I runt the script and get this eror.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Records] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Records_dbo.Users_UserId] 
FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) 
--ON DELETE CASCADE
```

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Records_dbo.Users_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "MyDb", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.

Not sure how to troubleshoot it... Tested both with and without the cascade...

Comment: are there rows in both tables? may be data-conflict not allowing? did you try creating on empty schema?

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: The error message is pretty clearly saying you have a FK on table `dbo.Users`.   I'd say you missed something when you say you checked that the table doesn't have a FK.   SQL Server generally doesn't make mistakes about things like this.   But humans do.

Comment: select *
from Records r
left join Users u on r.UserID = u.ID
where u.ID is null
That should show you the row(s) that have a value in Records that doesn't exist in Users.

Comment: @techspider Post it as a reply. You're genius! Unbelievably stupid mistake. Took me over two hours of swearing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be something to do with the existing data.  There must be some records conflicting the foreign key creation.  Try to create the key on an empty schema to see if it works.  Use WITH NOCHECK to not to check existing rows at the time of foreign key creation, if you need that data.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have a UserId in the Records table that does not exist in the Users table. This will certainly happen if you've been using 0 or some other value as a "default" value.